# О порядке слов. РФ баскетбола

Tags: ономастика, аббревиатуры

«С августа 2015 г. — Президент Российской федерации баскетбола.»

Мы имеем как минимум две РФ: просто РФ и РФ баскетбола? Возникает вопрос: нельзя было избежать нелепости? РФБ могла быть и Всероссийской федерацией, как волейбольная ВФВ (или Общероссийской), могла быть БФР — Баскетбольной федерацией России.

Похожая история со сборными России, а казалось бы, должна быть одна, так нет: все они — сборная России по фехтованию, сборная России по гребному слалому и т.д., — не просто команды. Следовательно, вся делегация должна называть себя сборной сборных?

Answer (score 2):

> Возникает вопрос: нельзя было избежать нелепости?

Ну на каждом углу соломки не подстелишь. Мало ли кому какая нелепая аналогия в голову придет. Мне наличие "двух РФ" абсолютно не мешает. Тем более что вторая существует только в аббревиатуре РФБ.

> Следовательно, вся делегация должна называть себя сборной сборных?

Не вижу ничего противоестественного в такой трактовке. Но для простого понимания достаточно просто "сборная России", к тому же официальной **делегации** статус сборной никто не присваивал.

Comment: Здесь два момента, две рф и два президента рф. Аббревиатура действительно «не мешает», а точнее — мало кто с ней сталкивается но есть такая важная вещь, как звучание. От звука трудно увернуться. Если про статус сборной говорить, то надо признать, что неофициальное на олимпиадах давно уже стало главным.